# Javascript Get the actual url to fill a form

Tags: javascript, forms, url, fill

I'm acually new to Javascript and want to add a little javascript code to my WP website.

I want to do is be able to fill an URL part of my form with the actual URL.
For example : `we're on`www.example.com/test1 and there is a form on it with several informations and there is an URL field to fill.

I want that this field is field with the actual url `www.example.com/test1`

Acutally I know i have to use the `window.location.href` in my Javascript but how to make it fill the form ?

**EDIT** (Form part) :

```
                        <div class="job_application application">

        <input type="button" class="application_button button" value="Postuler" />

        <div class="application_details">
            <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f89-p76-o1" lang="fr-FR" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/wp/poste/recruitment-intern-human-resources-knowledge/#wpcf7-f89-p76-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="89" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.7" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="fr_FR" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f89-p76-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="2a4920fb40" />
</div>
<p><label> Votre nom (obligatoire)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Votre prénom(obligatoire)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-forename"><input type="text" name="your-forename" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Votre adresse de messagerie (obligatoire)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Numéro de Téléphone (obligatoire)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-tel"><input type="tel" name="your-tel" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Votre CV (obligatoire)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-cv"><input type="file" name="your-cv" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Votre Lettre de Motivation (obligatoire)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-lm"><input type="file" name="your-lm" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Commentaire<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><label> URL<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="url" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-url wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-url" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>       </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            <div class="shapely-next-prev row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                <div class="wrapper"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span> <a href="http://192.168.125.218/wp/poste/ubisoft-montreuil-france-6-assistante-chargee-de-communication-interne-h-f-stage-6-mois-janvier-2019-communications-pr/" rel="prev">Assistant(e) Chargé(e) de Communication Interne H/F &#8211; Stage 6 mois &#8211; Janvier 2019 (Communications &#038; PR)</a></div>         </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                            </div>
        </div>


            </article>
        </div><!-- #primary -->
            </div>

</div><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: Can you show us your html so we can help you more precisely, please? The idea will be to take the element, for example, by id and use the innerText property for instance. But we should know your HTML.

Comment: @BrankVictoria check the EDIT of original post

Comment: I'm starting with this  `function autoFill() 
{
    document.getElementById('your-subject').value = "URL";
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do what you need is by get the DOM element using the property for example "type"

```
document.querySelector('[type="url"]').value = window.location.href;
```

Of course if you have different DOM Elements with that type I would recommend you to assign it a unique id and then you can use as follows:

```
document.getElementById("myURLField").value = window.location.href;
```

Comment: I have a unique ID already which you can see is called "your-subject". Is it preferable to add this :  `function autoFill() 
 {
document.getElementById("your-subject").value = window.location.href;
    }` in the end of the page or at the beginning

Comment: @B.Felix Watch out, "your-subject" in the code you've posted it is not an ID, for use the function getElementById you must set the attribute "id" with that value because it wont work with other attributes. And to answer your question, if you will paste the javascript in the HTML I would put it on the final. If you have a separate javascript file it doesn't matter always if the HTML is rendered.

Comment: Also take into account that if you want to use the attribute "name" you can use the querySelectorAll :)

Comment: Sorry if you missunderstand me, it is not necesary to declare the id="your-subject" it will work with your current HTML using `document.querySelectorAll('[name="your-subject"]').value = window.location.href;`

Comment: So should I declare it or not in the URL field ?

Comment: In your case it is not necesary.

Comment: This should be your autofill function `function autoFill() { document.querySelectorAll('[name="your-subject"]').value = window.location.href; }`

Comment: Exactly what I did, yet it doesnt fill the URL part of the form. May the problem come from the fact that the form show only when you click on the apply button ?

Comment: Did you place the call of the funcion autoFill() at the final of your HTML?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5eY3x7 Check it here line 1 to 38 is what I send you already but check line 92 there's the js function. It's in the end with most of my scripts

Comment: Yes, but you just have declared the function autoFill() you are never calling it, that's why it is not executing and not filling the URL Field

Comment: Okay so i'm calling the function when anyone is clickling the apply button but yet doenst fill the field. Check codeshare : https://codeshare.io/5eY3x7 (line 3)

Comment: I am so sorry, I have misswritten it is actually `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` check out my edited answer and put it as it is. I have tested with your code and it works with that.

Comment: Exactly perfect ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Javascript :

```
 function autoFill() 
    {
document.querySelector('[name="your-subject"]').value = window.location.href;
    }
```

HTML call the function in your input with HTML events(oclick,onload,...)